# Login architechture for a local java desktop application

Tags: java, authentication, architecture, desktop-application

**Hi,**
I am trying to write my first simple local desktop application with login capabilities. There should be support for different types of users with different access rights. I have managed to come up with something that works in a simple version of the program, however, it feels flawed on several levels. I simply don't know if I am on the right track with the structure of the entire application. I am also very uncertain about security.

**Here is my current implementation** (only the login specific classes/methods)**:**
[image: UML diagram over the login architechture]

**Question:**
Does anyone have recommendations for how to implement this kind of system? Or is there somewhere I can learn more about how to structure an application in a way that makes sense? I have been learning a lot of design patterns and OOB principals, but I have a hard time applying them in a real application.

**NB:**
If context matters, the application is a fictional computer store that lets administrators add different types of computer components to an inventory. Customers can search and filter through these parts and create their own configuration. Customers can then order that configuration.

Comment: I would use Spring (with Hibernate) as BackEnd, Prime, Thymeleaf and React for FrontEnd.
Oh, also I would prefer to make the ER diagram before the class diagram I have learned that most times you need the ER most than the class one (in quick projects). Hope It Help.

Comment: Plus, I would use an MVC like architecture with services and a facade (like you have done). What do you think ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check out what an MVC architecture is.

I am not really looking to use frameworks (or code that other people have written). The application is just a simple program locally run on one computer with one user at a time, meaning there is a blurry line between backend and frontend as there is really no server running. The purpose is just to learn how to create a simple application.

Comment: Reading the comment you put in the answer below, I think it would be enough with Java and using the swing library or with python. Or even you could do it using JavaScript (but use MVC).

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of the password feature? If it runs on a machine that is under the control of some user and not under yours, they *will* have access. There's nothing you can do about this.

Generally, for apps that run entirely locally, piggyback on the OS itself; store the data in the user's home dir and make sure the file's access rights are such that other (non-admin) users can't read it. Other admin users? Well, they are admin users. If they wanna read it, they can, that's sort of the point of such users. You can't stop them from doing this. If you store the relevant data per user in a file that only they can read, there's no need for a username/password prompt at all; their 'login' is their local username, and their 'authentication' is inherent. Simple.

The one time where a user/pass setup MIGHT make sense is if the app is started by an administrator and is started in a locked down mode, where the one operating the keyboard and mouse cannot get at the case of the system and cannot close the app at all. That's for example how an ATM works: Those are just windows machines, where the 'keyboard' is just a numpad, and the mouse and the computer system itself are locked away in a bunch of brick and metal. If you do this, make sure you apply proper password hygiene; don't store it, store its bcrypt/pbkdf/argon2/scrypt hash instead. That way if someone gets at that file, your app is hosed but at least if that user re-used their passwords on other sites (which users do, in spades), the hack won't expose that too.

I assume you don't have that, which brings us back to: What are you attempting to accomplish with the password?

Comment: I get that you can get around the password/username. However, this not a real project. I am assuming that all you can do is use the GUI of the application and not peak into any files.

This is a part of an assignment, so I don't make the rules :/